# How to test IsKindOfClass in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Seems simple but I can't find the answer anywhere? 
I just want to test whether an object is an instance of a certain class.
There's the `IsKindOfClass` method, but what argument can I pass it?

I wanted to write it like in Objective-C :

```
if (view.IsKindOfClass(AdvicePageView.Class)) {
```

but the Class method / attribute doesn't exist.

How can I pass my class to IsKindOfClass?

Comment: You'd have to pass in a `ObjCRuntime.Class` object into this method. You can use the `Class.GetHandle` methods to turn types by name or .NET types that subclass `NSObject` into a `Class` instance: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/ObjCRuntime.Class/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is basic C#

```
if (MyView is MyTypeOfView) then
```

where MyView is an instance and MyTypeOfView is a class